# Flutter and redux actions

Tags: flutter, redux

In React, you can have actions and dispatch like this

```
dispatch({ type: types.SOME_TYPE, data })
```

and then in the reducer switch the action type

```
switch (action.type) {
  case types.SOME_TYPE:
    return [ ...state, action.data ]

  default:
    return state
}
```

and I would add whatever was passed to the action to the store in the reducer

I am trying to do the same in Flutter.

```
const SOME_TYPE = 'SOME_TYPE';

void someAction(Store<AppState> store, data) {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'SOME_TYPE', data: data});
}
```

Where the data is passed from the view when dispatching the action

Is it possible to do this in Flutter? When I try this it says ****undefined name type****

The reducer then would be something like this

```
List<String> someReducer(List state, dynamic action) {
  switch (action['type']) {
    case 'SOME_TYPE':
      return [...state, action['data']];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

It doesn't even have to have this shape or work this way, what I want is to have an array in the store intitalized empty, someArray = []

Then from the views, I need to dispatch different actions  and each action adds a string to this array

Comment: It would be very helpful if you posted a minimal reproducible code sample for your reducer. And yes it is possible in flutter

Comment: @abiudrn I added the reducer and a little explanation of what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

the execution is correct. the main issue here is the type comparison. I would suggest:

1. Making the types as enums

   ```
    enum Actions { SomeAction }
   ```
2. Try out with an if statement to see if the comparison works ok

   ```
    if(action == Actions.SomeAction) {
       return [...state, action['data']];
       return state
      }
   ```
3. If that works then you can use packages such as [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) for easier type checking in your reducer.